# Have vim ai obey the formatting of spaces from the previous line

Tags: vim

When I indent/format my code I use tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment. I feel that this is intuitive and very effective at keeping code nicely formatted independent of the tab width of other programmers (as long as they are using monospace).

I like to keep my code nicely formatted for other potential developers and this is one thing about vim that irks me and I want to know if there is a solution. Using the ai format in vim if you have a line that is 2 tabs followed by 9 spaces (assuming 4 space wide tabs) when you enter a new line vim will have the new line be 4 tabs and 1 space. Which is not the desired behavior( I would like it to be 2 tabs and 9 spaces, like the previous line).

My question is, is this even possible? If no, why not? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set noexpandtab
set copyindent
set preserveindent
set softtabstop=0
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
```

It will add spaces though, if your current indentation is not a multiple of `tabstop`.

Comment: This worked, but could you please elaborate on what you mean by the last line? I already had tab stop set to 4 in my rc so it is probably something I am aware of but I want to make sure.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make preserveindent insert/delete tabs at the beginning when using commands like >> and <<? the default behaviour seems sub-optimal